# Python Multiprocessing QueueFeederThread won't close even though the Queue is empty

Tags: python, multithreading

My Python script hangs because the QueueFeederThread is still alive even after I think it should have joined and died. I make sure to empty the queue of any left-over items (that the consumers may have missed) by doing BOTH a:

```py
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
# ...
# Putting stuff into the queue, spawning subprocesses, consuming from queue, etc.
# ...

# At this point the subprocesses have joined, but we will have a few things left
# in the queue, so I do:
while not q.empty():
     foo(q.get())
```

and then, just to be super-duper extra sure since I know Queue.empty() isn't 100% reliable, I do this to flush it:

```py
while True:
    try:
        q.get_nowait()
    except:
        break
```

which should flush the entirety of the queue. But even after doing this, and the exception of the queue being empty is raised, the thread won't die.

Comment: You might be able to get some help with this if you provide a full, minimal, reproducible example.  Can you update your answer to include a complete Python script which demonstrates the issue you are having?